# QGIS freezes after making and saving many edits to a layer

Tags: qgis, editing

I work with QGIS 2.4 on windows 7.

The problem occurs when I work on a layer and save it many times. After a random number of saves, pressing the save button once more causes QGIS to freeze, all processor being used for more than two minutes. Exiting the edit mode for the layer also causes that behaviour.

The only solution to the problem is relaunching qgis. Saving the project does not cause a freeze, but clearing the  actual project does. And with that button the freeze will not recover, so I have to kill QGIS.

Has anyone encountered the same issue, or has any idea about it ?

Comment: I use QGIS 2.2 and it began to grind to a halt because of the amount of plugins I installed and kept active. Disabling most might help, otherwise if it is a size issue as @AndreJ mentioned then follow his answer :)

Comment: I also have this problem since version 2.0 (I am currently) on 2.10.1. I work in Kubuntu 15.04, but this bug occured also in precedent version of kubuntu. Only 1 of my CPU (I have a i7) is at 100%. The others are free. The first time the bug occur, the processor freeze for 1 minutes or so. If I don't quit QGIS and continu to work, the others freezes are more frequents and lst for longuer. The shape file size (memory and features) don't seem to be important.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem and it seems that disabling some plugins solves this issue. In my case I disabled TraceEditing and Rectangle Ovals Digitizing, following the discussion here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9229

Comment: Right, we had similar issue. Disabling some plug-ins fixed the problem

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problems with an earlier version of QGIS, and solved the problem by storing my data in spatialite databases.

The shapefiles I used before seamed to have reached a critical size (not in Gigabyte, but number of features). Especially point shapefiles, like bus stops, which tend to grow rapidly.

Comment: Thank you AndreJ. You're probably right, as this issue only occured to me in projects containing many layers and features. I already noticed that spatialite databases respond quicker that the same amount of info in many different shapefiles. I'll try to find a way to convert all shapefiles into a spatialite database.